# how to make a batch file that can reduce resolution and open a media player that i wanna to configure

Tags: video, batch-file, command

you all know that there is too hard to play hd movie in notebook and this problem become worst when there is a 1080p movie and larger resolution
 but I got the solution when i have windows xp installed i watched so many 1080p movies without any problem but when i upgraded to windows 8 I am unable to play 1080p movie lot of lags and often display driver not responding problem
 by chance i got a solution that is when we reduce the resolution of computer we can play true hd movie flawlessly in mpc-hc (cccp)

so I need a batch file or commands for cmd or a programm with which I can associate my media player with that batch file so that whenever I run that batch file it will open up my media player and lower the resolution (720*480 or 640*480) at same time
and when i close the programme it will change my screen resolution back to 1024*768
i can do this manually but it is big pain to this always when u wanna play hd files

pls solve my problem it is too important to me

Comment: one possible way is to edit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI` but this will require restart.

Answer (score 0):

nircmd can change resolution in a batch file

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

`Set the display mode to 800x600x24bit colors`

```
nircmd.exe setdisplay 800 600 24
```